# Why default parameters are not allowed before non-default ones?

Tags: c++

[Probable duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123725/why-should-default-parameters-be-added-last-in-c-functions)

So this is not allowed

```
void foo (int a, int b = 10, int c);
```

But why? Why not allow to call it like this? Two successive comas mean "use default parameter".

```
foo (20,,30);
```

Is there any real reason apart from "This not allowed because this is not allowed" and "This is not allowed because no one has put it to the committee"?

EDIT:
Ok, what about this

```
void bar (int a, int b, int c = 1, 
          int d = 2, int e = 3, 
          int f = 4, int g = 5, int h = 6);
```

Valid declaration, however I want to skip all default args except `h`.

wouldn't it be nice to be able to do this:

```
bar (20, 30, , , , , , 10);
```

Comment: I'd say that `foo (20,,30);` was a bad idea because from reading the code I can't tell what the value of the default parameter is or what it means. However, I know that it's there and that bugs me. When you have default parameters missed off the end, the function should still *read* correctly. For example, `std::sort(begin, end)` is perfectly understandable and so is `std::sort(begin, end, std::greater)`. If the comparison function had been the 2nd parameter though, the missing argument here would have confused me without reading the documentation: `std::sort(begin,,end);`

Comment: @sftrabbit "... I can't tell what the value of the default parameter is": Well, it's the same with the available syntax for default parameters...

Comment: A nice feature would be "named" parameters on the call side, like `foo(a := 20, c := 30)` but this is against the principle that parameter names aren't part of the signature... (Anyway, that's maybe the only thing i like about Visual Basic)

Comment: @aleguna: What advantage do you think this brings that is worth the increased complexity and ambiguity?

Comment: named parameters should come to the rescue

Comment: Wow, are you serious about your latest edit?

Comment: *Sometimes* it makes sense to group parameters (that form a logical group) to a struct / class and let its constructor set defaults. Only overwrite the ones you want to be different in some setters. In this case it would become maybe `Config c; c.setH(10); f(20, 30, c);` -- Of course it's not always the best design and should be handled with care. One example in practice is the GridBagLayout in Java / Swing and its constraints (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) Keep in mind that reusing such an object is dangerous (that's why I don't like this in general.)

Comment: "Why not allow to call it like this?" Because. Also, nobody will ever even think of a solution like this where keyword arguments solve this problem in a much better way.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus ... which isn't available in C++ neither. And please don't refer to Boost Parameter Library, it's such a huge ugly hack.

Comment: @leemes: Why is re-using the object dangerous? It would be in Java but in C++ you can simply take a copy without needing to mess about.

Comment: Not sure why it's closed "non constructive". D&E has a definitive reason. Should be closed "duplicate" instead, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123725/why-should-default-parameters-be-added-last-in-c-functions

Comment: @JackAidley I'm thinking about: `Config c; c.setH(10); f(c); ... f(c);` Then you want to change some parameter for the first call but overlook that it's reused for the second call (for which you *don't* want to change anything). So you gonna write sth like `Config c; c.setX(20); ... // the rest stays the same` so it also affects the second call accidentally.

Comment: @leemes Irrelevant, and also BPL is hardly the only implementation of keyword arguments.

Comment: @leemes In response to your first reply to me: It's not the same because when you leave off a default parameter at the moment, you don't really see that it's not there. The function still reads correctly. It doesn't bug me because I can't see that anything is missing and I don't *need* to know what is missing.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about the people that designed the language, but I find `f (20,,30);` terribly unreadable.

Comment: Hm, for me this is perfectly readable and blindly obvious that the default value will be used for the missing arg

Comment: FTR, I have used languages that support this, and this opinion is borne from that experience. I don't like counting commas.

Comment: Think of how it would be readable if there are more parameters f (20,,a,1,,,30)...

Comment: Ok, lets suppose that this is unreadable. Surely this has never been a valid excuse for the commette - look at lambda syntax.

Comment: Yet lots of functions have just a few parameters and for them it would be OK

Comment: `Foo( bar,,,, qux)` <--- I think I'd kill myself.

Comment: Surely `foo(1,2);` is worse - you can't even determine how many default parameters are being hidden (unlike `foo(1,2,,);`).

Comment: Guys, the fact that this can be abused horribly to `f (20,,a,1,,,30)` is irrelevant.

Comment: @Brendan One cannot really compare readability from examples with poor naming: both `foo(1,2)` and `foo(1,2,,);` are absolutely inscrutable and both clearly "foo the ones and twos" to me.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, there are lots and lots of C/C++ features which can be abused to make code totally unreadable. That is not a point.

Comment: @aleguna I know that. See comment above. However, I think this feature makes code hard to read most of the time and *requires care* to work otherwise. (if you think otherwise, you'd better show proper examples in your question; and badly named functions don't help make an argument for readability; show examples with *real-looking* functions)

Comment: @Brendan: The difference is not really between `foo(1,2,,,,)` and `foo(1,2)`. In both cases a quick glance will tell you that the first two arguments have values and the rest does not. The problem is that in `foo(1,,,,,2)` that is not obvious and you need to *count* characters and a small one for what matters to know what `2` means. Better than that the language could support named arguments `foo(1,arg5=2)` which would be readable and allow for skipping intermediate arguments. That was proposed for the standard long ago, and dropped due to the separate compilation model (can expand if needed)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Interesting that you answered and at the same time voted to close as *not constructive*. I would have assumed that either it is non-constructive and thus does not grant an answer, or it should be answered and then it is a valid question (I am inclined on the latter... while this is technically not a 'code' question, it is related to programming and there are reasons for language design decisions...

Comment: @David - I'd tend to agree. I downvoted on this one, as it would have been better a comment. Interestingly, a contributor who had a much smaller rep said almost exactly the same thing, and got -2 for it before the answer was deleted entirely `:-O`