# Why are the default arguments provided for trailing arguments only

Tags: c++, function

Why does the compiler give an error for the below declaration

```
void fun(int a = 10,int b);
```

I stumbled upon this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637679/default-argument-in-the-middle-of-parameter-list). But I am still not sure why the C++ compiler puts this restriction.

Comment: How would you call this function specifying only the value of `b`?

Comment: oh. Such a simple thing. Sorry for bothering.

Comment: This was already answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123725/why-should-default-parameters-be-added-last-in-c-functions

Comment: @interjay: `fun(, 5)` :D