# Why can you only supply default arguments at the end of the parameter list in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

Why can you only supply default arguments at the end of the parameter list? What is the main reason behind this?

```
Linklist<T>::Linklist(int a, int b, int  c = 20){}
why cant it be
Linklist<T>::Linklist(int a, int b=10, int  c ){}
```

I was told this is due to name mangling. But I cannot really understand how that affects this. Can anyone explain this point clearly.
Is it just the we cant specify the use the default parameter in calling this function if they are random?

Comment: That's just how C++'s syntax was designed. Other languages have named parameters, C++ doesn't, although similar idioms exist.

Comment: It is one of two conventions I can think of that allows to map arguments to parameters unambiguously, the other one being the continuous range being at the start of the parameter list. That one would be confusing.

Comment: Mostly an ambiguity problem with function overloading. It's easier for the compiler to tell if the function is overloaded properly if only the trailing arguments can be defaulted, otherwise if would have to test for every possible permutation

Comment: Too  bad the selected answer in the duplicate is actually wrong.

Comment: Yes, That is the real reason i feel this is nt duplicate to that.

Comment: This is nt a duplicate as the answers avaialble in the other thread are not satisfactory for some reason.i think this has to deal with function overloading, but not sure about the excat reason.

Comment: You're right that name mangling has nothing to do with it. The second answer (Matthieu M's) in the linked dupe is pretty good.

Comment: Unfortunately, the quality of the answers does not come into it. The *question* is a duplicate. You could consider taking this to meta and ask what to do when a duplicate doesn't have answers to the question.

Comment: iam new to stackoverflow and hwo to take this to meta?just cheing it now.

Comment: i found in strousrup's book that  by introducing default arguments to reduce the number of constructors.probablky, this could be one of the reason

Comment: Better dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123725/why-should-default-parameters-be-added-last-in-c-functions But a dupe non the less.

Comment: I think Matthieu's answer is valid. In the end it is a language design decision. C doesn't have named parameters, so the only alternatives that come to mind are all the default parameters at the front or at the back.

Comment: @BaummitAugen With another wrong selected answer. Why on earth would one have to call `foo(, 3);` and not `foo(3);`? It seems hard for some to see the symmetry between leading and trailing default parameters :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza Damnit, that just got me too. :S

Comment: @juanchopanza : From Stroustroup's book, this answer is something which is convincing  that introducing default arguments will  reduce the number of constructors

Comment: @user2256825 That isn't an answer to the question you're asking. That is an answer to "why are default parameters  good idea?"

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123725/why-should-default-parameters-be-added-last-in-c-functions

Comment: Perhaps , that's what I have understood clearly . Yes you are right , the question would be different

Comment: No, this is valid: `void f(int a, int b = 42); void f(int a = 42, int b);` (hint: trick).